# How to save a complex matrix in a file?

Tags: python, numpy

i have to save a matrix shown below with complex data into a file with .H extension using savetxt command of numpy but i am not able to save it.the matrix to be saved is

```
[[   1.0+0.j    0.0+0.j    0.0+0.j]
 [   1.0+0.j    1.0+0.j    0.0+0.j]
 [   2.0+0.j    2.0+0.j    0.0+0.j]
 ..., 
 [ 683.0+0.j  688.0+0.j   -2.7+0.j]
 [ 684.0+0.j  689.0+0.j   -2.7+0.j]
 [ 685.0+0.j  690.0+0.j   -2.7+0.j]]
```

i have tried this command but its giving error

```
>>savetxt('H.H',H_new.H,fmt='%.4e%+.4j%.4e%+.4j%.4e%+.4j',delimiter=' ');
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 974, in savetxt
    % fmt)
AttributeError: fmt has wrong number of % formats.  %.4e%+.4j%.4e%+.4j%.4e%+.4j
```

Comment: What version of numpy are you using?  (Check `numpy.__version__`.)

Comment: i am using 1.6.1 version of numpy

Comment: I updated my answer with a method that works in numpy 1.6.1.

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i updated my numpy to 1.7.1 and ur earliar solution is working fine

Comment: i have one more query that if i want to import this same complex values containing file in my program what procedure should i follow?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply its working perfectly in my code

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is missing some format characters.  Try something like

```
fmt='%.4e%+.4ej %.4e%+.4ej %.4e%+.4ej'
```

But it looks like you'll need numpy 1.7.0 or later; see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/1475319160baed782daa39e0de0c0655c2abe4b5

It worked for me with numpy 1.8.0, but not with 1.6.1.

With numpy 1.6.1, you can save the data in this format by first creating a real view of the complex data.

In this example (an ipython session), I'm using numpy 1.6.1:

```
In [28]: np.__version__
Out[28]: '1.6.1'
```

`z` is a complex array, with shape (2, 3):

```
In [29]: z
Out[29]: 
array([[ 1.+2.j, -3.+4.j,  5.-6.j],
       [-1.+0.j,  0.+2.j,  3.+0.j]])
```

Use the `view` method to create a real array with shape (2, 6):

```
In [30]: rz = z.view(float)

In [31]: rz
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1.,  2., -3.,  4.,  5., -6.],
       [-1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.]])
```

Save the array using `savetxt`.  The format string uses the entire row, so there is no need to give the `delimiter` argument:

```
In [32]: savetxt('z.txt', rz, fmt='%.4e%+.4ej %.4e%+.4ej %.4e%+.4ej')
```

Take a look at the output:

```
In [33]: !cat z.txt
1.0000e+00+2.0000e+00j -3.0000e+00+4.0000e+00j 5.0000e+00-6.0000e+00j
-1.0000e+00+0.0000e+00j 0.0000e+00+2.0000e+00j 3.0000e+00+0.0000e+00j
```

This file can be read back into a numpy array with `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`.  To use `loadtxt`, it must be told that the data type is complex:

```
In [8]: loadtxt('z.txt', dtype=np.complex128)
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1.+2.j, -3.+4.j,  5.-6.j],
       [-1.+0.j,  0.+2.j,  3.+0.j]])
```

`genfromtxt` works with the same arguments. `genfromtxt` can also attempt to determine the data type on its own, by giving the argument `dtype=None`.  This works for complex values:

```
In [9]: genfromtxt('z.txt', dtype=None)
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1.+2.j, -3.+4.j,  5.-6.j],
       [-1.+0.j,  0.+2.j,  3.+0.j]])
```