# Writing and reading complex numbers using numpy.savetxt and numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I need to write and read complex numbers. I would like to use `numpy.savetxt` and `numpy.loadtxt` to do so. Since the code that I have written is rather big I created a test file to try to write and read complex numbers.

So far I have been able to write complex numbers using `numpy.savetxt`. The code is the following:

```
import numpy

d1 = -0.240921619563 - 0.0303165074169j
d2 = -0.340921619563 - 0.0403165074169j
d3 = -0.440921619563 - 0.0503165074169j
d4 = -0.540921619563 - 0.0603165074169j

array = numpy.array([d1, d2, d3, d4])

save = open("test.dat", "w")
numpy.savetxt(save, array.reshape(1, array.shape[0]), newline = "\r\n", fmt = "%.10f")

save.close()
```

This gives the following output:

```
 (-0.2409216196+-0.0303165074j)  (-0.3409216196+-0.0403165074j)  (-0.4409216196+-0.0503165074j)  (-0.5409216196+-0.0603165074j)
```

All that I now want to be able to do is actually read/load the data. The script I have is:

```
import numpy

d = numpy.loadtxt("test.dat")
```

This piece of code is not sufficient and I am currently unable to load the data. My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121271/numpy-read-complex-numbers-from-text-file). However, by manually replacing the `+-` by a `-` I am still unable to load the data. I think the solution lies in the `dtype` option for `numpy.loadtxt`. I have not been able to figure it out though.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012484/how-to-save-a-complex-matrix-in-a-file/

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use `loadtxt` and `savetxt` rather than just `load` and `save` or `tofile` and `fromfile`?

Comment: Isn't this a bug in numpy? In my opinion `savetxt` should provide a correctly formatted complex numbers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Warren Weckesser! The link you suggested helped me a lot. I now have two working scripts: one for writing complex numbers using `numpy.savetxt` and one for reading/loading the complex numbers from the file using `numpy.loadtxt`.

For future references, the codes are listed below.

Writing:

```
import numpy

d1 = -0.240921619563-0.0303165074169j
d2 = -0.340921619563-0.0403165074169j
d3 = -0.440921619563-0.0503165074169j
d4 = -0.540921619563-0.0603165074169j

array = numpy.array([d1, d2, d3, d4])

save = open("test.dat","w")
numpy.savetxt(save, array.reshape(1, array.shape[0]), newline = "\r\n", fmt = '%.4f%+.4fj '*4)

save.close()
```

Reading/Loading:

```
import numpy

coeffs = numpy.loadtxt("test.dat", dtype = numpy.complex128)
```