# Reading complex data into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to read complex numbers from a text file into a numpy array. My question is similar to this one [Writing and reading complex numbers using numpy.savetxt and numpy.loadtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231698/writing-and-reading-complex-numbers-using-numpy-savetxt-and-numpy-loadtxt) however, the solution here is to alter the format the data is saved in. I don't have this luxury as the text file is generate by other software which I cannot change. A sample of the text file is a follows:

```
25 + 0i
8.43818 + -4.94194i
4.46817 + -5.08305i
4.55764 + -3.02201i
2.69138 + -5.43104i
-0.151334 + -4.83717i
1.98336 + -1.3339i
3.59002 + -0.932973i
1.42727 + -0.617317i
1.02005 + -1.14214i
-0.15564 + 2.74564i
```

I have tried the following:

```
np.loadtxt('file.txt',delimiter='\n',dtype=np.complex128)
```

However I get the error:

```
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string
```

The posts I have read suggest this is an issue with the `+ -` notation in some lines, however, I get the same error even if the extra `+` signs are removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> however, the solution here is to alter the format the data is saved in

Good news, you don't have to!

`numpy.loadtxt` can take any iterable of lines, not just a file object.

So, you can wrap your file object in a simple generator that transforms the lines on the fly, and feed that to `loadtxt`, and everyone will be happy.

Like this:

```
def transform_complex(line):
    # insert your code here

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    lines = map(transform_complex, f)
    arr = np.loadtxt(lines, dtype=np.complex128)
```

(If you're using Python 2.x, and the file is large, you probably want to use `itertools.imap` rather than `map`.)

The "insert your code here" part, you fill in from the answer that worked, but wasn't an acceptable solution because it required modifying the files. Since I don't see such an answer in your link, I'm not sure what that is, but for example, maybe it's this:

```
def transform_complex(line):
    return line.replace(b'+ -', b'- ')
```

---

Testing things out locally, it looks like there are actually three things wrong with your input.

You can test what the output *should* look like using `savetxt`. For example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1-2j])
>>> f = io.BytesIO()
>>> np.savetxt(f, arr)
>>> f.getvalue()
b' (1.000000000000000000e+00-2.000000000000000000e+00j)\n'
```

(In Python 2.x, you won't see the `b` prefix.)

Not all of those differences turn out to be relevant—you don't have to use exponential notation, you don't need parens, etc.—but it looks like these three are:

- No spaces allowed around the `+` in complex numbers.
- The imaginary unit has to be `j`, not `i`.
- No `+-` allowed.

So:

```
def transform_complex(line):
    return line.replace(b' ', b'').replace(b'+-', b'-').replace(b'i', b'j')
```

Answer (score 2):

@abarnert's answer is fine, but don't forget that `loadtxt` has an argument, `converters`,
that provides a hook for customizing how a field is processed.  Here are a couple
examples that show how it can be used to process this file.

In the first version, the default delimiter (whitespace) is retained,
so there are three columns.
`usecols` is used to ignore the middle column (the '+').  A converter is used to
convert the last column (column 2) to a floating point value.  It uses a slice to discard
the last character, which is the 'i'.  With these arguments, `loadtxt` returns an array
with shape (11, 2) of floating point values.  By calling the `view` method with the
type `np.complex128`, the array is converted to an array of floating point values
with shape (11, 1).  Finally, indexing with `[:,0]` gives the 1D array of complex values.
(A call to `ravel`, `squeeze`, or `reshape` could have been used instead.)

```
In [24]: loadtxt('file.txt', converters={2:lambda f: float(f[:-1])}, usecols=(0,2)).view(np.complex128)[:,0]
Out[24]: 
array([ 25.000000+0.j      ,   8.438180-4.94194j ,   4.468170-5.08305j ,
         4.557640-3.02201j ,   2.691380-5.43104j ,  -0.151334-4.83717j ,
         1.983360-1.3339j  ,   3.590020-0.932973j,   1.427270-0.617317j,
         1.020050-1.14214j ,  -0.155640+2.74564j ])
```

The next version treats the entire line as a single field.  The following function
converts a string in the format used in the file to a complex number:

```
In [36]: def to_complex(field):
   ....:     return complex(field.replace(' ', '').replace('+-', '-').replace('i', 'j'))
   ....:
```

E.g

```
In [39]: to_complex('8.43818 + -4.94194i')
Out[39]: (8.43818-4.94194j)
```

This call to `loadtxt` treats each line as a single field, and uses
the converter to convert each field to a complex number:

```
In [37]: loadtxt('file.txt', converters={0: to_complex}, dtype=np.complex128, delimiter=';')
Out[37]: 
array([ 25.000000+0.j      ,   8.438180-4.94194j ,   4.468170-5.08305j ,
         4.557640-3.02201j ,   2.691380-5.43104j ,  -0.151334-4.83717j ,
         1.983360-1.3339j  ,   3.590020-0.932973j,   1.427270-0.617317j,
         1.020050-1.14214j ,  -0.155640+2.74564j ])
```

(The delimiter is set to `';'`, but it could have been any character that
doesn't occur in the file.)