# Read a file consisting two columns of pure(?) double into a complex NumPy array

Tags: numpy

**Almost the same** questions were asked by the following:

[Numpy read complex numbers from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121271/numpy-read-complex-numbers-from-text-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Writing and reading complex numbers using numpy.savetxt and numpy.loadtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231698/writing-and-reading-complex-numbers-using-numpy-savetxt-and-numpy-loadtxt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[loading complex numbers with numpy.loadtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348824/loading-complex-numbers-with-numpy-loadtxt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Reading complex data into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022899/reading-complex-data-into-numpy-array)

However, the above involved slightly different input format, e.g. parentheses, than the file content herein.

---

Consider a file named `example` containing **two columns of *pure(?)* double**:

```
0.8355544313622164  0
1.199174279986189   0
1.417275292218002   0
```

I am able to generate a `numpy array` of `np.complex64` by doing the following:

```
data = np.loadtxt("./example", dtype=np.float64, delimiter='\t')
complexData = data.T[0] + 1j*data.T[1]
```

Printing `complexData` now gives:

```
[ 0.83555443+0.j  1.19917428+0.j  1.41727529+0.j ... ]
```

Is it possible to reduce the above approach into a neater one?

---

For example, changing data type to `np.complex64` raises `TypeError`:

```
data = np.loadtxt("./example", dtype=np.complex64, delimiter='\t')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting the real array to complex with

```
complexData = data.T[0] + 1j*data.T[1]
```

you can create a complex *view* of the data:

```
complexData = data.view(np.complex128)
```

Then `data` and `complexData` share the underlying array of floating point numbers, but `complexData` interprets those values as complex numbers.

`complexData` will be an array with shape (n, 1).  To get rid of the extraneous second dimension, you can use

```
complexData = data.view(np.complex128)[:, 0]
```

You could do the conversion immediately upon reading the data.  For example, my sample file called `"real.txt"` is

```
0.8355544313622164  0
1.199174279986189   0
1.417275292218002   0
3.141592653589793   -1
```

and it is not tab-delimited, so I'll use the default delimiter.  To read the data as complex:

```
In [18]: z = np.loadtxt('real.txt').view(np.complex128)[:, 0]

In [19]: z
Out[19]: array([0.83555443+0.j, 1.19917428+0.j, 1.41727529+0.j, 3.14159265-1.j])
```